# (bs4) trying to differentiate different containers in a HTML page

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, urllib

I have a web page from the Houses of Parlament. it has information on MP declared interests and I would like to store all MP interests for a project that I am thinking of.

```
root = 'https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm/cmregmem/160606/abbott_diane.htm'
```

root is an example webpage. I want my output to be a dictionary, as there are interests under different sub headings and the entry could be a list.

Problem: if you look at the page, the first interest, (employment and earnings) is not wrapped up in a container, but rather the heading is a

tag, and not connected to the text underneath it so I could call `soup.find_all('p', {xlms='<p, {'xmlns':'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')`
but it would return the headings of expenses, and a few other headings like her name, and not the text under it. 
which makes it difficult to iterate through the headings and storing the information

What would be the best way of iterating through the page, storing each heading, and the information under each heading?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ret = {}
page = urllib.request.urlopen("https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm/cmregmem/160606/abbott_diane.htm")
content = page.read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
valid = False
value = ""

for i in soup.findAll('p'):
    if i.find('strong') and i.text is not None:
        # ignore first pass
        if valid:
           ret[key] = value
           value = ""
        valid = True
        key = i.text
    elif i.text is not None:
        value = value + " " + i.text

# get last entry
if key is not None:
    ret[key] = value

for x in ret:
    print (x)
    print (ret[x])
```

Outputs

```
4. Visits outside the UK
Name of donor: (1) Stop Aids (2) Aids Alliance Address of donor: (1) Grayston Centre, 28 Charles St, London N1 6HT (2) Preece House, 91-101 Davigdor Rd, Hove BN3 1RE Amount of donation (or estimate of the probable value): for myself and a member of staff, flights £2,784, accommodation £380.52, other travel costs £172, per diems £183; total £3,519.52. These costs were divided equally between both donors. Destination of visit: Uganda Date of visit: 11-14 November 2015 Purpose of visit: to visit the different organisations and charities (development) in regards to AIDS and HIV. (Registered 09 December 2015)Name of donor: Muslim Charities Forum Address of donor: 6 Whitehorse Mews, 37 Westminster Bridge Road, London SE1 7QD Amount of donation (or estimate of the probable value): for a member of staff and myself, return flights to Nairobi £5,170; one night's accommodation in Hargeisa £107.57; one night's accommodation in Borama £36.21; total £5,313.78 Destination of visit: Somaliland  Date of visit: 7-10 April 2016 Purpose of visit: to visit the different refugee camps and charities (development) in regards to the severe drought in Somaliland.  (Registered 18 May 2016)Name of donor: British-Swiss Chamber of Commerce     Address of donor: Bleicherweg, 128002, Zurich, Switzerland Amount of donation (or estimate of the probable value): flights £200.14; one night's accommodation £177, train fare Geneva to Zurich £110; total £487.14 Destination of visit: Geneva and Zurich, Switzerland Date of visit: 28-29 April 2016 Purpose of visit: to participate in a public panel discussion in Geneva in front of British-Swiss Chamber of Commerce, its members and guests. (Registered 18 May 2016) 
2. (b) Any other support not included in Category 2(a)
Name of donor: Ann Pettifor Address of donor: private Amount of donation or nature and value if donation in kind: £1,651.07 towards rent of an office for my mayoral campaign  Date received: 28 August 2015 Date accepted: 30 September 2015 Donor status: individual (Registered 08 October 2015)
1. Employment and earnings
Fees received for co-presenting BBC’s ‘This Week’ TV programme.  Address: BBC Broadcasting House, Portland Place, London W1A 1AA. (Registered 04 November 2013)14 May 2015, received £700. Hours: 3 hrs. (Registered 03 June 2015)4 June 2015, received £700. Hours: 3 hrs. (Registered 01 July 2015)18 June 2015, received £700. Hours: 3 hrs. (Registered 01 July 2015)16 July 2015, received £700. Hours: 3 hrs. (Registered 07 August 2015)8 January 2016, received £700 for an appearance on 17 December 2015. Hours: 3 hrs. (Registered 14 January 2016)28 July 2015, received £4,000 for taking part in Grant Thornton’s panel at the JLA/FD Intelligence Post-election event. Address: JLA, 14 Berners Street, London W1T 3LJ. Hours: 5 hrs. (Registered 07 August 2015)23rd October 2015, received £1,500 for co-presenting BBC’s "Have I Got News for You" TV programme. Address: Hat Trick Productions, 33 Oval Road Camden, London NW1 7EA. Hours: 5 hrs. (Registered 26 October 2015)10 October 2015, received £1,400 for taking part in a talk at the New Wolsey Theatre in Ipswich. Address: Clive Conway Productions, 32 Grove St, Oxford OX2 7JT. Hours: 5 hrs.  (Registered 26 October 2015)21 March 2016, received £4,000 via Speakers Corner (London) Ltd, Unit 31, Highbury Studios, 10 Hornsey Street, London N7 8EL, from Thompson Reuters, Canary Wharf, London E14 5EP, for speaking and consulting on a panel. Hours: 10 hrs. (Registered 06 April 2016)
Abbott, Ms Diane (Hackney North and Stoke Newington)


House of Commons



Session 2016-17

Publications on the internet
```